# How to stop the current thread till other thread complete its execution?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

Here is my problem ...

```
 public static String response = "";
```

'

```
 public static String sendDataToServer(String data)
  {
    new Thread()  
    {
     public void run()
     {
     //sending data to server
     response = httpClient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();
    }

    } .start();   

   return response;

  }
```

When i call this method i'am getting empty string as response.

```
String res = sendDataToServer("my_data");  //res is always empty string
 //...XXXXXXX code after calling the method
```

And always XXXXX code is getting executed before finishing the execution of sendDataToServer() method.  Why res is always empty ? How do i get the correct response string ? How can i stop the XXXX code being executed before execution of sendDataServer() method ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you _really_ want to wait, don't start a thread, just call `response = httpClient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();` right away.

Comment: But you probably don't want to wait since it will either error because it violates StrictMode or it results in ANR. Call some method at the end of `run` to notify your code about the result - [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is good for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //sending data to server
        response =
              httpClient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();
    }
 };
 t.start();
 t.join();
```

this way you will wait until the thread finishes and jsut then continue.

However, keep in mind that waiting for thread to finish is dangerous in Android, especially in UI thread (that is the main thread). However, I assume that this thread is not in UI thread, because otherwise `AsyncTask` would have been better solution (and more native).

Comment: This answer, while correct, does not make much sense. Why create another thread if you are going to join it immediately? Just execute the code on the parent thread.

Comment: Actually I think I got the upvotes because the comment of `AsyncTask`. I also do not see any sense in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join() to wait for a thread, but since your thread, the following does the same thing.

```
public static String sendDataToServer(String data) {
     //sending data to server
     return httpClient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to syncronize thread execution. As stand in the doc, a CountDownLatch allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes. If the thread starting sendDataToServer is the UI or main thread, of course this will result in issue in responsives of your apps. Give more details.